# What do I need to know/do inorder to create a Flex swf that works both online, and on a phone's browser?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mobile, air

I am aware of the new FlashBuilder 4.5 mobile application settings.  I am aware that it uses an enhanced version of AIR to make apps that work well on mobile devices, which would normally mean that I can't have it run in the browser.  I'm also aware that I should be able to get the enhanced performance if I create a swf with the correct compiler settings, and use the correct base components for my application.

What are the correct base components? Spark or MX or something else?
What are the correct compiler settings?

I need the application to work for both desktop users, and mobile users who visit the website through their flash enabled browser.

There are three important features for me.

1. Being able to load a file from the mobile device/computer.
2. Being able to have the softkeyboard activated when needed.
3. Good mobile performance

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close.  Question is too broad and user hasn't done research on his own.

Answer (score 0):

normally i would build each one on it's own .. and that would give the right results
here is some advices from adobe ..
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/training-with-trani/multiscreen-best-practices-/
i know that this is for screen resolutions but i guess that it is relevant .
good luck